# Dialling Offline Twilio Client

Tags: twilio

I need to make calls to some Twilio clients that will received the call through the browser. The problem is, these clients don't necessarily have their browser open.

I know normally, a user would have to open up the browser and through the twilio util capability and twilio device to turn their browser into a device. And THEN they can receive incoming call.

Is there way to dial clients, when they haven't initialize their twilio client yet?

Comment: If the client software isn't initialised, how will you know where to send the call?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you try to dial a client who is not online Twilio will view that as a no-answer.  You can get a notification of this by [providing a URL for the `<Dial>` verbs action parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#examples-2).

When the call ends Twilio will make a request to this URL with a parameter named [DialCallStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action-dial-call-status-values) which you can use to determine what happened when Twilio tried to dial the Client.

Hope that helps.